# NetSuite Email - Payments

Tags: netsuite

Does anyone know if it is possible to email a link to receive a credit card payment though NetSuite?

Scenario: When email of Invoice is sent, a link to a NetSuite form for the client to pay that Invoice is sent. Without having to login, the client can click the link and make the payment (or send us the CC info for us to process with).

Thanks in advance,
Alexis

Comment: We know there is the client portal but we want to be able to provide the client a simple way to send the payment info. Without the need to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with an externally available Suitelet.  You can customize the link in your email to include the internal id of the Invoice.

When your customer clicks on the link, the suitelet will create a form where they can enter their payment information.  Then the script will get the internal id of the invoice from the url parameter and save the info provided by your customer.

Comment: This is not recommended because it will be a security risk specially if you are dealing with CC information.

Answer (score 0):

You need a payment gateway that will securely get the CC information.